# R: iterating over two columns of 0's and 1's to make one column of 0's and 1's

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

Matrix:

```
   A   B
   0   1
   0   0
   1   0
```

I have a design matrix in which my first two columns are 'A' and 'B' are populated by 0's and 1's I need to replace these two columns with one that summarises both of them ie. in one new overarching column a 1 will be in the place where either one of the A and B were a 1 and a 0 where they were both 0.

my attempt is as follows:

```
  x <- vector("list", length(my_mat)) #empty vector
    for(i in 1:length(design[2])) #fill vector with column content
      ifelse(attempt[ ,1]==1|attempt[ ,2]==1, x[i]<-design[i], x[i]<-0) #in event that either A or B is 1 give x vector a 1 other wise give it a 0
  as.matrix(x)
  my_mat<-my_mat[ ,-c(1,2)] #get rid of first two columns
  my_mat<-cbind(my_mat, x) #summarise first two columns by binding the other new one
```

My problem is that the vector that I get is full of NULL values so I'm doing something wrong as it should just have  just made a vector of 0's and 1's

Note I would prefer to be able to access the columns with the "$" note but I get the following error, as the original data is not a data frame:
Error in design$Culture_confirmed_TB : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: I guess you want `as.integer(rowSums(m[, c("A","B")]) > 0L)` or `as.integer(m[,"A"] + m[, "B"] > 0L)` or `pmax(m[,"A"], m[, "B"])`?

Comment: Another standard solution is `answer <- apply(matrixName, 1, max)` although it is slower than `rowSums`.

Comment: Thanks very much ur first suggestion helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original data is

```
tab <- data.frame(A = c(0L, 0L, 1L), B = c(1L, 0L, 0L))
```

Then adding the new column can be achieved like this:

```
tab$C <- (tab$A | tab$B) + 0
tab
#   A B C
# 1 0 1 1
# 2 0 0 0
# 3 1 0 1
```

---

If the data is a `matrix`,

```
M <- cbind(A = c(0L, 0L, 1L), B = c(1L, 0L, 0L))
```

then adding the new column can be done like this

```
M <- cbind(M, C = M[,1] | M[,2])
```

Comment: Coercion to integer would be better than to float, and you can do it with `as.integer`. Also, I guess a design matrix is a *matrix*, not a data.frame..?

Comment: yeah it's a matrix

Comment: Hi Vincent thanks very much unfortunately my original data is in matrix format so I get the following error:
Error in design$Culture_confirmed_TB : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
I will update the question accordingly